# singular points of $f(\frac{1}{z})$

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

given an entire function $f(z)$, find and classify the singular points of the function $f(\frac{1}{z})$.

my take:

$f(z)$ is entire -> $f(z)$ = $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n  z^n$

plugging in $\frac{1}{z}$ -> $f(\frac{1}{z})$ = $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n  z^{-n}$

we define $g(z) = f(\frac{1}{z}) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^0 a_{-n}z^n$

1. $f(z)$ - polynomial
   $lim_{z\to0} f(1/z) =\infty $ - z=0 is a pole
2. $f(z)$ is constant
   $lim_{z\to0} f(1/z) = Const $ - z=0 is a removeable singularity
3. $f(z) $ is not a polynomial then the laurent expansion is of the form :
   $f(z)$ = $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n  z^n$
   we get infinite negative exponents when $z= \frac{1}{z}$ and so z=0 is an essential singularity.

Comment: This question had appeared a few hours ago: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4172641/find-and-classify-all-isolated-singularities-of-f-frac1z-given-f-is-e?noredirect=1#comment8643739_4172641

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thank you! I edited my question

Comment: Why would $g$ tend to infinity as $z\to 0$? Look at the expansion of $\exp(1/z)$ and see what happens when you let $z\to 0-$ on the real line. There will be one singular point: $z=0$. This will be an isolated singularity which can be either removable, a pole or an essential singularity. Can you show that any of those can occur with some appropriate $f$?

Comment: @Gary Thank you!! I edited my question, with your help , plop and KaviRamaMurthy I think I got it!